# SF short story about a future in which jobs are assigned by DNA

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story is about a person riding in a limo, speaking about all the things he enjoys daily and specifically about the wood grain of the limo. You learn that your job is assigned by DNA and that if you create something good enough, a person whose DNA is suited to enjoy things will enjoy your creation. The enjoyers use things only once and live lavish lifestyles to keep this "economy" going. The enjoyer/main character laments about creating things himself.

I may have read it on a site like WIRED or something, but I can't find it.

Comment: @centarianone - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and do you have any sense of how old the story was?